# Android Studio: OneSignal causing problem

Tags: android, android-studio

Am trying to fix an old project and OneSignal is creating problem.

But when I remove this like compile `'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.8.3, 3.99.99]'` everything works fine. So how do I fix this? I need OneSingnal for Push notification. What should I do?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 123
        versionName "1.1.0.123"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id : "--------------------",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {}
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'

    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.andrognito.pinlockview:pinlockview:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.pro100svitlo:fingerprintAuthHelper:1.3.0'

    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.pchmn:MaterialChipsInput:1.0.5'

    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.8.3, 3.99.99]'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the Error I get now

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.3.99
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.3.99
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.3.99
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.3.99
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.99
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.99
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.99
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.3.99
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Answer (score 0):

could you please check if google play services is installed on your android studio sdk tools?
[image: android studio - android sdk settings]

Here's my edit. It might be related to a version misalignment. Try to get the latest ones with this change in your build file.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:+'
```

Comment: Yes. Its installed